# Android Timezone.getDefault() gives Asia/Calcutta and not Asia/Kolkata

Tags: android, timezone

I am using the Android TimeZone functionality and my app is communicating with a server that expects Asia/Kolkata from devices in India. However, when getting the `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()`, I get Asia/Calcutta and not Kolkata. Knowing that when printing the values in `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`, it shows both, Calcutta and Kolkata. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both should be valid.  The zone used to be called `Asia/Calcutta` and was renamed to `Asia/Kolkata`, but there is still an alias in the tzdb that points the old name to the new one.  [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

If the server doesn't allow the new name, then they need to update their tz files from [here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), or in whatever implementation they might be using.

If you can't do that, you can always catch this case and replace the string yourself.  They are equivalent zones.