# ANDROID : TimeZone object returns Asia/Calcutta as Default Timezone instead Asia/Kolkata

Tags: java, android, timezone

I am Developing an app that fetches device default timezone and send it to the server. For this i have used android's TimeZone class. Following is my code...

```
TimeZone defaultTimezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

I printed the Timezone id into the Logcat...usingfollowing line..

```
Log.e("TimeZone","DefaultTimeZone -> " +
             " id = " + defaultTimezone.getID());
```

and in Logcat it's showing like this...

```
E/TimeZone: DefaultTimeZone ->  id = Asia/Calcutta
```

i don't know how to solve this but i want timezone as **Asia/Kolkata** instead of Asia/Calcutta...

**Edit : **
Kolkata is city in India which is renamed from Calcutta

Comment: whats wrong with renaming it manually

Comment: Check this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590376/android-timezone-getdefault-gives-asia-calcutta-and-not-asia-kolkata

Comment: @eriuzo what if same problem occurs with any other timezone?