# Why Python pytz package has both Asia/Kolkata and Asia/Calcutta timezones?

Tags: python, django, pytz

I was working on a dropdown with list of all timezones and I took the list of timezones from Python **pytz** package. I noticed that Asia/Kolkata and Asia/Calcutta both appear in the list where as Asia/Calcutta has been renamed to Asia/Kolkata. Is there a reason pytz is not removing the obsolete timezones?

Same with Asia/Katmandu and Asia/Kathmandu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Timezone.getDefault() gives Asia/Calcutta and not Asia/Kolkata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590376/android-timezone-getdefault-gives-asia-calcutta-and-not-asia-kolkata)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97630):

> Oh, I remember this. Asia/Calcutta was used in the tz database until
> several years ago. Now, Asia/Kolkata replaces this and Asia/Calcutta
> is in backward file. ICU/CLDR has "stable" ID policy - so ICU/CLDR
> still uses "Asia/Calcutta" as a "canonical time zone ID" and
> "Asia/Kolkata" as an alias. So, in ICU, both Asia/Calcutta and
> Asia/Kolkata work fine - but when you try to get canonical ID via API,
> it will be "Asia/Calcutta", instead of "Asia/Kolkata"

So it is an alias and not an obsolete name.

It is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590376/android-timezone-getdefault-gives-asia-calcutta-and-not-asia-kolkata)